# Grabbed and compelled movement

Tags: movement, pathfinder-2e

We know that we have to [contest the Grab on *forced movement*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/179716/9552).

What happens if we make the grabber *want* to move? Consider a [Command](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=45) to *approach*, or [Hypnotic Lure](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3987).
Will it drag the victim along, or release it?
Is there any guidance, or is it up to the DM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the grabber moves, no matter the reason, the victim is released, as per the [grapple rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=35):

> **Critical Success** Your target is restrained until the end of your next turn *unless you move* or your target Escapes.
>
> **Success** Your target is grabbed until the end of your next turn *unless you move* or your target Escapes.

Compelling the grabber to move with a spell or [shoving](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=38) it away from the victim, both would have that effect.

For completeness, tripping the grabber does not end the grapple, since gaining the prone condition from a trip is not movement, but if the grabber [stands up](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=86) (and usually they will want to), that is a move action and would release the victim.
On the other hand, if the grappler [Drops prone](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=78) by its own volition or compelled by a command spell, that would release the victim, since the drop prone action is a move action too.

Comment: would tripping the grabber down to prone position release the victim?

Comment: @FrancescoRogo, added to the question

Comment: thank you, pretty clear

Comment: Note that Grab (the action used by monsters) uses different wording that Grapple (the action used by players), and the conditions are different. So this answer is only a partial answer.